# How can I solve a KeyError in my code, I'm a begginer

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror

I'm resolving a basic problem consisting of make a list of products, the user choose the product and the amount of the product and the total price is printed. I get a keyerror in the line 22.

```
def main():
   print("Choose a product: ")
    print("")
    print("Products: ")
    print("")
    print("Samsung Galaxy S10+.............1")
    print("Samsung Galaxy S10..............2")
    print("OnePlus 7 Pro...................3")
    print("OnePlus 7.......................4")
    print("OnePlus 6t......................5")
    print("Huawei P30 Pro..................6")
    print("Huawei Mate 20 Pro..............7")
    print("Google Pixel 3XL................8")
    print("Gooogle Pixel 3A XL.............9")
    print("Oppo Reno 10x Zooom............10")
    print("")

    relation = {1:1000, 2:900, 3:700, 4:600, 5:470, 6:850, 7:970, 8:950, 9:300, 10:550}

    code = input("Enter the product code: ")
    print("")
    print("The price is $", relation[code])
    quantify = input("Enter amount: ")
    print("")

    totalPrice = float(relation[code] * quantify)

    print("The total price is: $", totalPrice)
```

The error displayed is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 22, in main
    print("The price is $", relation[code])
KeyError: '5'
```

In this case I choose the product code "5".

Comment: `int(input("Enter amount: "))`. The `input` function returns a string, but your dictionary keys are ints.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `input` it returns a string, not an integer. You can see this because the error message shows `'5'`, not `5`. The keys to your dictionary are integers, though, so the key you are providing in the statement (`code`) is not found.
You could instead use

```
print("The price is $", relation[int(code)])
```

A better format, at least in Python 3.6 and later, would be

```
print(f"The price is ${relation[int(code)]}")
```

for line 26, the problem is similar. Just convert to integers (or float, if there's a decimal point)

```
totalPrice = float(relation[int(code)] * int(quantify))
```

or

```
totalPrice = relation[int(code)] * float(quantify)
```

Comment: I resolved the problem in line 22 but now I have the same problem (keyerror) in line 26 :(

Comment: Thank u so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

`input` in python receives data as a string, you need to typecast it

it is something along:

`print("The price is $", relation[int(code)])`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also follow the Python idiom [EAFP (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp) here when asking for user input as he could write literally everything but integers you expect:

```
while True:
    code = input("Enter the product code: ")

    try:
        price = relation[int(code)]
    except (ValueError, KeyError):
        print("Error: Incorrect code value, try again!")
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    print("Choose a product: ")
    print("")
    print("Products: ")
    print("")
    print("Samsung Galaxy S10+.............1")
    print("Samsung Galaxy S10..............2")
    print("OnePlus 7 Pro...................3")
    print("OnePlus 7.......................4")
    print("OnePlus 6t......................5")
    print("Huawei P30 Pro..................6")
    print("Huawei Mate 20 Pro..............7")
    print("Google Pixel 3XL................8")
    print("Gooogle Pixel 3A XL.............9")
    print("Oppo Reno 10x Zooom............10")
    print("")

    relation = {1:1000, 2:900, 3:700, 4:600, 5:470, 6:850, 7:970, 8:950, 9:300, 10:550}

   code = input("Enter the product code: ")
   print("")
   print("The price is $", relation[code])
   quantify = input("Enter amount: ")
   print("")

   totalPrice = float(relation[int(code)] * quantify)

   print("The total price is: $", totalPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to take the input as integer because the input() take the default as a string so you can type it like  `quantify = int(input("Enter amount: "))`
or another method is to use int() in the place where the calculations are like
`totalPrice = float(relation[int(code)] * int(quantify))`